# Send Distinguished Name ADFS 2.0

Tags: adfs2.0

Can you guys help me out on how to send DN in a claim from ADFS 2.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a standard URI for DN but you can always roll your own.

The ADFS claims rules box is actually configurable - refer [ADFS : Selecting claim that's not in the default drop down](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2011/09/adfs-selecting-claim-thats-not-in.html)

So in the "LDAP Attribute" enter "DN" and in the "Outgoing Claim Type" enter something like "http://company.com/identity/claims/DistinguishedName".

**Edited:**

LDAP attributes see here : [Selected LDAP Attributes](http://www.skills-1st.co.uk/papers/ldap-attributes/selected-LDAP-attributes.pdf)

Comment: It worked! Just one small modification. In the "LDAP Attribute" use "distinguishedname" instead of "DN". I have tried to find some overview of the LDAP attributes that are available from Active Directory. Do you know of anything like this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"), query = "; distinguishedName;{0}", param = c.Value);