# Restricting ADFS 2.0 to use a specific OU instead of Domain level access

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs2.0, adfs, claims

Consider the below Sample Scenario:

- I have a Single Active Directory Domain for Production, Test and for development (each separated  at OU level).
- I want to install ADFS at test OU level and I do not want users authenticated at test OU ADFS to have access (both read and write) to other OU's.

Can this be possible ? Can we restrict ADFS 2.0 to work only under a particular OU ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though restricting ADFS 2.0 to work under a specific OU is not feasible (from the resources I read and IMHO), we can restrict the user access within a specific OU.

This can be accomplished in two steps:

1. Add a claim rule to extract AD object DN.

   • To extract this claim, from ADFS admin console, go to ADFS 2.0 - >
       Trust Relationship -> Claims provider Trusts -> Click on the Active
       Directory -> Edit claim rules.

   • Under acceptance transformation
       rule, add a new rule

   ```
          Claim rule name – DN (can be anything)
          LDAP Attribute – distinguishedname 
          Outgoing claim type – http://temp.org/claims/DistinguishedName
   ```

   • This will extract the DN   of each object in the AD
2. Add a new authorization rule (in relying party trust of the required application) to allow users from a particular OU to access the application.

   •    Go to ADFS admin console ->  Trust Relationship ->Relying party trusts -> Select the application -> Edit claim rules

   •  Under Issuance authorization rules (second tab), remove the existing rule “ Allow all users” (if any) and add a new rule under - Send claims using a custom rule:
   Name:  XXX (any value)

   ```
   Custome rule: 

   c:[Type == "http://temp.org/claims/DistinguishedName", Value =~"^.*    (OU=EMPLOYEES,OU=Org-Users,DC=ADCORP,DC=LAB)$"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Value = "PermitUsersWithClaim");
   ```

   For example:
    Users in OU=Users,OU=EMPLOYEES,OU=Org-users,DC=ADCORP,DC=LAB would have access

   Users in OU=Admins,OU=EMPLOYEES,OU=Org-Users,DC=ADCORP,DC=LAB would have access

   Users in OU=Users,OU=CONTRACTORS,OU=Org-Users,DC=ADCORP,DC=LAB  would NOT have access

For more details about adding DN, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968455/send-distinguished-name-adfs-2-0) and for details about adding the custom rule, refer to the [msdn post.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/winserverDS/thread/762a4ab1-1649-442c-91a4-654ee7b3664f)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to reverse the restrictions?  So instead of allowing just 1 OU at a time could you allow everyone but one?

So the string could be

C:[Type == "http://temp.org/claims/DistinguishedName", Value =~"^.*    (OU=EMPLOYEES,OU=Org-Users,DC=ADCORP,DC=LAB)$"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/deny", Value = "PermitUsersWithClaim");

This way everyone but the Employees OU would have access.