# MVC Authorization based on OU in LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, authorization, adfs

I have set up authorization using LDAP and ADFS. How can I restrict access to a controller or action based on the OU the user belongs to?

[UPDATE]

I already have authentication set up to the user I want. What I need is to be able to limit access to a controller/action based on what ON users belong to in Active Directory.

For example:

[Auhtorize(OU="MYOU")]
public class Controller

I tried using roles but it didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352332/restricting-adfs-2-0-to-use-a-specific-ou-instead-of-domain-level-access

Comment: Sure this won't work THAT easy. You'll need a custom authorization attribute to check OU claims.

Comment: This could well be the worst hack ever! but given that [Authorize] only takes Role / User then have a claim rule to get the DN, then use regexreplace rules to trim that down to the OU then take that claim and issue to a Role claim ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - refer: [Restricting ADFS 2.0 to use a specific OU instead of Domain level access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15352332/9922).

Note that this is an authorization rule rather than a claims rule.